# Menu does not collapse on mobile when clicked on items other than Home

Tags: jquery, css

I just created a new page, valid only for devices right now. I tested only for Android (iOS in the future).

You can take a look at the page here : http://www.suale.it/prova/cqc/index.html

The main problem is that every time I change page in the menu, menu does not collapse itself.

I tried with this code in the quiz.js file to collapse the menu, but has no effect:

```
var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
x.className = "topnav";
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: so when you change to like "GoTo" your menu will collapse?

Comment: Question isn't clear :(

Comment: Please add more code in the question here, like the function being called on click and some HTML rather than asking people to view and debug your website.

Comment: @sam did you resolve this issue? did any answer work or was the issue something else?
Please either accept an answer or edit the question to add more information and how you resolved it if different so it helps other people in future.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'd like to collapse the menu when switching pages on mobile devices.

You only added that line for the Home() function. You need to call the same hide lines on each tab click:

```
function DIVGoTo() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    x.className = "topnav";

    $('div[id^="div"]').hide();
    $('#About').hide();
    $('#GoTo').show();
    $('#txtGOTO').focus();

    $("#header-content").hide();
}

function About() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    x.className = "topnav";

    $('div[id^="div"]').hide();
    $('#GoTo').hide();
    $('#About').show();
}
```

Comment: yes, but already exist for about(), and it seems not working properly

Comment: Could you paste the code of quiz.js? The page you posted doesn't have those lines within those functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following code in your onclick functions (at the end of **DIVGoTo** and **About**).

```
var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
x.className = "topnav";
```

This should collapse your menus once the page switches. Its the same as on your myFunction works, but basically you already know the menu was displayed thats why this click method was invoked. Currently you have added the above code in **GoTO** but you have not called it in your menu, you actually call **DIVGoTo**.

Comment: @sam please comment here if this does not resolve the problem or remember to accept the answer if it does. Thanks!

Comment: OP says this didn't resolved his issue. I posted the same answer and requested more information or an updated test site

Comment: I think he did not realize he is adding the code to a copy of the function thats dead code now. Thats why i mentioned the function name he added the code to and the one that actually gets called.